# Get facebook education into $_SESSION

Tags: php, facebook-php-sdk

```
<?php
session_start();

require 'config.php';
require 'facebook.php';

$facebook = new Facebook(array(
        'appId'     =>  $appID,
        'secret'    => $appSecret,
        ));
$user = $facebook->getUser();

if($user){

    try{
        $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
        $params = array('next' => 'website' );
        $logout =$facebook->getLogoutUrl($params);
        $_SESSION['User']=$user_profile;
        $college = null;
        foreach ($user_profile['education'] as $education) { 
            if ($education['type'] == "College") { //store the name data
                $college = $education;
                break;
            }
        }

        if(empty($college)) {
    echo "College information was not found!";
} else {
    // var_dump($college);
    echo "name" . json_encode($college);
}

?>
```

return in page

```
name{"school":{"id":"1234567890","name":"Universiti Tunku Abdul Rahman"},"type":"College"}
```

i get the college data from Facebook sdk , i only want the school name and store into $_SESSION how am i going to do that? is a array i dont how i going to get the data store into $_SESSION.

Comment: Hej, check out php.net website. It's pretty cool and you should read some before even trying to write PHP scripts.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to store an array into a session variable in php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18499034/how-to-store-an-array-into-a-session-variable-in-php)

Comment: Learn the basics of PHP for some years first! You'll only run into huge problems if you are trying to build advanced things without knowing the super-basics.

Answer (score 0):

Use json_decode to read the array

```
$myArray = json_decode($data, true);
echo $myArray[0]['id']; // Fetches the first ID
echo $myArray[0]['name']; // Fetches the first name
```

Comment: $myArray = json_decode($college, true);
echo $myArray[0]['id']; // Fetches the first ID
echo $myArray[0]['name']; // Fetches the first name

Comment: it return  json_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in